# How do I return a struct or anything more complicated than a primitive?

Tags: rust

I've been tinkering with Rust and I'm a little confused with function return types. As an experiment I'm writing an IRC log parser. I'm familiar with the primitive types, and having functions return those. What about more complex types when returning multiple pieces of data?

```
/* Log line example from log.txt */
/* [17:35] <@botname> name1 [460/702] has challenged name2 [224/739] and taken them in combat! */

#[derive(Show)]
struct Challenger {
  challenger: String,
  defender: String
}


fn main() {
  let path = Path::new("log.txt");
  let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
  for line in file.lines() {
      let mut unwrapped_line = line.unwrap();
      let mut chal = challenges3(unwrapped_line);
      println!("Challenger: {}", chal.challenger);
      println!("Defender: {}", chal.defender);
  }
}

fn challenges3(text: String)-> Challenger {
  let s: String = text;
  let split: Vec<&str> = s.as_slice().split(' ').collect();
  if(split[4] == "has" && split[5] == "challenged") {
    let mychallenger = Challenger { challenger: split[2].to_string(), defender: split[6].to_string()};
    return mychallenger;
  }
}
```

I realize this code isn't very idiomatic, I'm getting familiar with the language.

I get an error with this code:

```
"mismatched types: expected `Challenger`, found `()` (expected struct Challenger, found ())"
```

How can I return a Struct or a HashMap? Is there a better way to return multiple fields of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` in `challenges3` has no `else` block, so if the condition isn't met, execution continues after the `if` block. There's nothing there, so the function implicitly returns `()` at this point. You must also return a `Challenger` after the `if` block, or [`panic!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic!.html) to abort the program.

Alternatively, you could change the return type of your function to `Option<Challenger>`. Return `Some(mychallenger)` in the `if` block, and `None` after the `if` block:

```
fn challenges3(text: String) -> Option<Challenger> {
    let s: String = text;
    let split: Vec<&str> = s.as_slice().split(' ').collect();
    if split[4] == "has" && split[5] == "challenged" {
        let mychallenger = Challenger { challenger: split[2].to_string(), defender: split[6].to_string()};
        return Some(mychallenger);
    }

    None
}
```

You can also use [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) instead of [`Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) if you want to return some information about the error.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped clear up a few things in the process. I'm sure I'll have more questions in the future :)